# How can we access newly generated files on a hosting website like heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, web, repository

I was working on a pet project wherein I was using heroku and git. After committing the code when I ran the website,some new web pages were created on heroku. Now ,I want to download all those new files onto my computer.How do I achieve this ?

I tried 
    `git clone git://project.url.here`
but it just downloaded the files I committed ,not the new ones that were generated on heroku.

Answer (score 2):

You would need for your app to have some kind of a /download endpoint where it would serve these new pages. Use authentication etc.

Just note that each time a Dyno is restarted it will erase all the files you've created. I'm assuming thy we're created on the file system of course.